# iOS MKAnnotation subtitle with NSMutableAttributedString possible

Tags: ios, mkannotation, nsattributedstring, subtitle, callout

I'm trying to have MKAnnotation subtitle to have colored text, but I can't achieve that with NSMutableAttributedString.

Does anyone have a idea how to achieve that?

My current code:

customAnn.h

```
interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@end
```

customAnn.m

```
@implementation MapAnnotation

- (NSString *)title
{
    return @"Some Title";
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *subPart = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [[[data valueForKey:@"16"] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] componentsJoinedByString:@" "]]];
    [subPart addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:20/225.0 green:30/255.0 blue:15/255.0 alpha:1] range:NSMakeRange(0, subPart.length)];
    return subPart;
}
@end
```

Currently the code is NOT working because `- (NSString *)subtitle` wants `NSString` but gets `NSMutableAttributedString` - it crashes, but if change to `- (NSMutableAttributedString *)subtitle` I can't even get it to compile.

I have no other ideas how to realize this.

Thanks.

Comment: Give us some code examples, so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to do that with a stock MKAnnotation. I would create my own custom annotation view, that way you can customize the view however you want.

Here's a good tutorial:

http://blog.asynchrony.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/